# Using a macro ends in error when using a special variable

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

SBCL 2.3.7

I want to save me from writing a format like this because I have a lot of variables (more than 3) and want to insert a semicolon between them:

```
(format nil "~a;~b;~c;" var1 var2 var3)
```

Expected result:

```
"a;b;c;"
```

I have defined a special variable and a macro.

```
(defparameter *delimiter* ";")

(defmacro format-delimited (stream fmt delimiter &body vars)
   (let ((fmtstr ""))
    (dotimes (i (length vars))
      (setf fmtstr (str:concat fmtstr fmt delimiter)))
    `(format ,stream ,fmtstr ,@vars)))
```

This call successfully returns:

```
(format-delimited nil "~a" ";" "a" "b" "c")
"a;b;c;"
```

macroexpand-1 returns:

```
(FORMAT NIL "~a;~a;~a;" "wolf" "golf" "rolf")
```

This call ends in error:

```
(format-delimited nil "~a" *delimiter* "a" "b" "c")

; Debugger entered on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: SEQUENCE datum: *DELIMITER*>
```

macroexpand-1 also ends in error.

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: If you use `str:concat` you can use `(str:join ";" '("wolf" "golf"))` ;) (you don't need a macro).

Comment: macros are expanded before they run. A macro gets source code passed, not runtime values. You thus can't compute a string at macro expansion time, when the code is not running and thus has no runtime values. -> you try to compute at macro expansion time, this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you use `str:concat`, so you can use `(str:join ";" '("wolf" "golf"))` (you don't need a macro).

`str:join` takes two arguments: the delimiter and a list of strings. If you want to write a varying number of strings without a list, like so:

```
(join-all ";" "wolf" "golf" "rolf" etc etc etc)
```

we can write a helper function. It will accept &rest arguments:

```lisp
(defun join-all (delimiter &rest strings)
     (funcall #'str:join delimiter strings))
```

=>

```lisp
(JOIN-ALL ";" "golf" "wolf" "rolf")
"golf;wolf;rolf"
```

`funcall` allows to call a function by name with its right number of arguments. The varying number of strings are grouped as a list thanks to `&rest strings`, so we can pass this list as argument to `str:join`.

---

- the "str" library: https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str/

Answer (score 4):

Just use the facilities already provided by `format`. You can use [`~{ ~}`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cgd.htm) to iterate over a list of arguments:

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~{~A;~}" '("a" "b" "c"))
"a;b;c;"
```

If you want to omit the final semicolon, you can use [`~^`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cib.htm) to escape the iteration once the final argument has been processed:

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~{~A~^;~}" '("a" "b" "c"))
"a;b;c"
```

Or `~@{` could be used to iterate over the format arguments as if they were in a list [(thanks @Jérôme Radix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77130744/using-a-macro-ends-in-error-when-using-a-special-variable/77130942?noredirect=1#comment136022983_77130942):

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~@{~A~^;~}" "a" "b" "c")
"a;b;c"
```

Note that this solution is limited by [call-arguments-limit](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_call_a.htm) as described further below.

You can use this idea to write a macro, e.g.:

```lisp
(defmacro format-delimited (delimiter stream format-string &rest args)
  `(format ,stream
           ,`(concatenate 'string "~{" ,format-string "~^" ,delimiter "~}")
           (list ,@args)))
```

```
CL-USER> (format-delimited ";" nil "~A" "a" "b" "c")
"a;b;c"
CL-USER> (let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
           (format-delimited ";" nil "~A" a b c))
"1;2;3"
CL-USER> (let ((a 'x) (b 'y) (c 'z))
           (format-delimited ";" nil "<~A>" a b c))
"<X>;<Y>;<Z>"
```

I'm not sure that there is any reason to write this as a macro; the above could be more simply written as a function:

```lisp
(defun format-delimited (delimiter stream fmt-str &rest args)
  (format stream
          (concatenate 'string "~{" fmt-str "~^" delimiter "~}")
          args))
```

This can be made more flexible, allowing the choice of placing delimiter strings before and after the output. This would accommodate OP example output `"a;b;c;"` as well as `"a;b;c"`, `";a;b;c"`, or `";a;b;c;"`. In the `format-delimited` function below the arguments to be printed are placed in a list; this makes it easier to use keyword arguments and clarifies the API:

```lisp
(defun format-delimited (stream fmt-str args &key (delim " ") init end)
  (let ((init (if init delim ""))
        (end (if end delim "")))
    (format stream
            (concatenate 'string init "~{" fmt-str "~^" delim "~}" end)
            args)))
```

Here are some example usages:

```
CL-USER> (format-delimited nil "~A" '(a b c))
"A B C"
CL-USER> (format-delimited nil "~A" '("a" "b" "c") :delim ";" :end t)
"a;b;c;"
CL-USER> (format-delimited nil "~A" '() :delim ";")
""
CL-USER> (format-delimited nil "~A" '(x) :delim ",")
"X"
CL-USER> (let ((x (/ 1.0 3))
               (y (sqrt 5))
               (z 2.99792458e8))
           (format-delimited nil "~10,3E" (list x y z) :delim "|" :init t :end t))
"|  3.333e-1|  2.236e+0|  2.998e+8|"
```

### When You Really Want to Join Strings

I was led to believe that OP wanted to format the values of variables using delimiters by the example `(format nil "~a;~b;~c;" var1 var2 var3)`. The final version of `format-delimited` above satisfies all of OP requirements, and provides quite a bit of flexibility in how output is formatted.

It has been suggested that the non-standard library function `str:join` can solve OP problem, and this may be true. It should be noted that this solution can join strings together with a delimiter, but does not provide a way to add the delimiter to the end (or the beginning) of the output.

If what is needed is a way to join strings with a delimiter, here is a portable solution written in standard Common Lisp that also allows flexibility in placing a delimiter string at either or both ends of the output:

```lisp
(defun string-delimited (args &key (delim " ") init end)
  (do* ((init (if init delim ""))
        (end (if end delim ""))
        (acc (list init)))
       ((endp args) (apply #'concatenate 'string (nreverse (cons end acc))))
    (push (pop args) acc)
    (when args (push delim acc))))
```

The above definition of `string-delimited` has a problem: the Common Lisp standard only requires that a function be able to handle 50 arguments. Because of this an input `args` list of more than 24 strings may fail when `concatenate` is applied to its arguments. Yet
this may be fine in practice for many uses; SBCL allows up to 1,073,741,824 arguments to be passed into function calls. Other implementations are less generous, e.g., Clisp allows only up to 4,096 arguments in function calls. The limit for any particular implementation can be found by checking the value of [call-arguments-limit](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_call_a.htm).

If this is a concern you can write `string-delimited` while avoiding `apply`:

```lisp
(defun string-delimited (args &key (delim " ") init end)
  (do* ((init (if init delim ""))
        (end (if end delim ""))
        (acc (string init)))
       ((endp args) (concatenate 'string (nreverse acc) end))
    (setf acc (concatenate 'string (pop args) acc))
    (when args (setf acc (concatenate 'string delim acc)))))
```

There are probably better ways to write this function; this implementation may be less efficient than the first one since `concatenate` is called many times, but it is not subject to the function arguments limit.

Example usages:

```
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a" "b" "c") :delim ";")
"a;b;c"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a" "b" "c") :delim ";" :end t)
"a;b;c;"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a") :delim ";")
"a"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '() :delim ";")
""
```

### A Better Version of `string-delimited`

Here is an improved version of `string-delimited` that uses `reduce` instead of `apply`. Using `reduce` avoids the problems with function argument limits that `apply` had. This version also mutates the result list instead of creating a fresh list when the end delimiter is added. Instead of using `do`, this version uses `loop` which seems to make the code a bit more clear and concise. Finally, the `show-empty` keyword has been added to control handling of empty input lists. Previous versions have always shown any specified outer delimiters when the input is an empty list.

```lisp
(defun string-delimited (args &key (delim " ") init end show-empty)
  "Takes a list of strings and joins them using the delimiter string.

ARGS must be a list of strings.

DELIM is a string that specifies the delimiter.

INIT is a boolean that indicates whether the delimiter should appear at the
     beginning of the concatenated result. Defaults to NIL.

END is a boolean that indicates whether the delimiter should appear at the
    end of the concatenated result. Defaults to NIL.

SHOW-EMPTY is a boolean that indicates how empty input lists should be
           handled. If this value is true, the delimiters specified by
           INIT and END will appear in the concatenated result even for
           empty input lists. Otherwise the outer delimiters will only
           appear in the result for non-empty input lists."
  (when (not (or args show-empty))
    (return-from string-delimited ""))
  (let ((result (cdr (loop for s in args
                           collecting delim
                           collecting s))))
    (when init (push delim result))
    (when end (setf (cdr (last result)) (list delim)))
    (reduce (lambda (&optional a b) (concatenate 'string a b)) result)))
```

Some example usages:

```
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a" "b" "c") :delim ";")
"a;b;c"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a" "b" "c") :delim ";" :init t :end t)
";a;b;c;"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a" "b" "c") :delim ";" :end t)
"a;b;c;"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a") :delim ";")
"a"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '("a") :delim ";" :init t :end t)
";a;"
CL-USER> (string-delimited '() :delim ";" :init t :end t)
""
CL-USER> (string-delimited '() :delim ";" :init t :end t :show-empty t)
";;"
```

Comment: Lots of interesting ideas, thx ! You could write `(format nil "~@{~A~^;~}" "a" "b" "c")` to obtain `"a;b;c"` without having to put the values into a list.

Comment: @JérômeRadix -- A good suggestion, and I have added it to my answer. Note that there is a limit to the number of arguments you can pass to `format`, and passing them in a list avoids the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The macro doesn't evaluate the `*delimiter*` expression; it works with the source code of that expression which is the `*delimiter*` symbol itself.

When the argument is `";"`, the difference between the two disappears, because `";"` is a self-evaluating atom: the source code for `";"` and the run-time value of `";"` are one and the same.

If your macro takes a parameter which is not going to be inserted into the expansion, but must be evaluated, and that parameter can be any expression (not just literals like `"abc"`, `42` or `'(1 2 3)` (quoted list), you have to use `eval` on it to get the value.

Let's change your `&body` to `&rest` because `vars` are not a `progn`-like body.

Let's also change the names of the macro parameters so that they remind us that they are expressions (source code) and not values:

```
(defmacro format-delimited (stream-expr fmt-expr delimiter-expr &rest var-exprs)
  (let ((resulting-fmtstr "")
        (incoming-fmt (eval fmt-expr))
        (delim (eval delimiter-expr)))
    (dotimes (i (length var-exprs))
      (setf resulting-fmtstr (concatenate 'string resulting-fmtstr incoming-fmt delim)))
    `(format ,stream-expr ,resulting-fmtstr ,@var-exprs)))
```

With this I get:

```
> (macroexpand '(format-delimited t "~a" ";" 1 2 3))
(FORMAT T "~a;~a;~a;" 1 2 3) ;
T
> (defvar *delimiter* "---")
*DELIMITER*
> (macroexpand '(format-delimited t "~a" *delimiter* 1 2 3))
(FORMAT T "~a---~a---~a---" 1 2 3) ;
T
```

Needless to say, the `eval` won't be happening in the apparent lexical environment. That does not exist until run time; at macro-expansion time, we are just processing source code.

The variable being referenced, `*delimiter*` will  have to exist at macro-expansion time and have the right value.

The `format` function can do what you're after. The syntax has a lot of bells and whistles. I'm not sure whether it can iterate a format string over multiple arguments, but it can do that with an argument that is a list of values.

You might be concerned that you don't want the format string to be interpreted at run-time.

Common Lisp has a macro called `formatter` which turns format strings into code (a function).

If you have

```
(format stream "whatever" args ...)
```

you can replace it with

```
(format stream (formatter "whatever") args ...)
```

to have that string `"whatever"` compiled. The result is a function (likely a `lambda` expression). When the second argument of `format` is a function, it just hands the stream and arguments off to that function.

Answer (score 2):

This is an absolutely classic example of a case where you should not be using a macro.

The semantics of `format-delimited` is that of a function: it is not a syntactic extension to the language in any way.  So it should *be* a function.  Further `format` has facilities which support *exactly this case*: you should use them.

Here is a simple example which works and which uses only CL facilities:

```
(defun format-delimited (stream format delimiter &rest args)
  (format stream (format nil "~~{~A~A~~}" format delimiter) args))
```

If you're really feeling your oats you can do this entirely within `format`:

```
(defun format-delimited (stream format delimiter &rest args)
  (format stream "~{~@?~A~}"
          (mapcan (lambda (arg)
                    (list format arg delimiter))
                  args)))
```

Now we could start worrying that, oh no, this calls `format` twice and/or conses a list, doom doom, we're wasting valuable cycles on the PDP-11 we think we're using.  So, OK, let's deal with that mostly-imaginary-problem, without breaking the semantics of the thing.

```
(defun constant-value (thing)
  ;; assuming THING is CONSTANTP, get its value.
  (if (and (consp thing) (eq (first thing) 'quote))
      (second thing)
    thing))

(define-compiler-macro format-delimited (&whole form
                                                stream format delimiter &rest args)
  (if (and (constantp format)
           (constantp delimiter))
      `(format ,stream ,(format nil "~~{~A~A~~}"
                                (constant-value format)
                                (constant-value delimiter))
               ,@args)
    form))
```

Now, for instance `(format-delimited t "~A" ";" ...)` will be turned by the compiler into `(format t "~{~A~;~}" ...)`.

You can also use `formatter` of course, which might make things better (but likely will not in this case).

Comment: The first 2 answers by Ehvince and Rainer Joswig are the proper solutions. I did mixed up  the behaviour of a function call and defmacro. I discarded my macro and used str:join. Thank you to all who replied.

Comment: @klk2ptx  Something to be aware of is that there is no `str` package or `str:join` in ANSI Common Lisp; you're using a vendor-specific extension or add-on library. In Common Lisp, you can join a list of strings using `(concatenate 'string <list-of-strings>)`. Some of the answers to this questions contain examples of its usage.